# Benefits of LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, loops

I have been fretting over this problem too long, however as I have not had any definitive answers, I will try to state the situation again, in a clearer fashion.

I have a questionaire, which allows administrators to add different categories and different questions for each category, therefore on inserts for each categories I cannot hard code parameters as I do not know how many questions the user will be answering.

Right now I have an SP which inserts (or updates) one row;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertResults]
    @userId nvarchar(10),
    @groupId INT ,
    @questionId INT,
    @answer INT 
AS
BEGIN 

SELECT *  FROM answers 
     WHERE   userId = @userId AND questionId = @questionId 
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0

INSERT  INTO answers
        (   userId,
    groupId,
    questionId,
    answer
        )
VALUES  ( 
        @userId,
    @groupId ,
    @questionId,
    @answer
        )
ELSE

UPDATE answers
SET answer = @answer
WHERE   userId = @userId AND questionId = @questionId 
END
```

then in C# I loop through all the questions;

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        var rb = gvr.FindControl("answers_list") as RadioButtonList;
        var quest = rb.SelectedValue;

        if (quest == "")
        {
            quest = "0";
        }

        int questionId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString());
        int groupId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Values[1].ToString());
        int question = Convert.ToInt32(quest);
        var objDB01 = new dbconn();
        const string strSQL = "insertResults";
        objDB01.objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", logonName);
        objDB01.objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groupId", groupId);
        objDB01.objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@questionId", questionId);
        objDB01.objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@answer", question);
        try
        {
            objDB01.GetNonQuery(strSQL);
        }
        finally
        {
            objDB01.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I have asked my own server team if opening and closing the DB so many times is bad coding  (sometimes there can be over 100 people answering over 100 questions simultaneously) but I cannot get an answer. I have asked here if there is a more efficient solution or if the use of LINQ in this scenario can improve performance - but I cannot get an answer.

I may not have the knowledge, but I am trying to learn to programme elegantly and your help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Where does LINQ come in? I don't see it used anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the app is a web based asp.net one.

In this scenario, asp.net will use Connection Pooling, so that while you may be opening and closing many connections in your code, in reality, .NET is only using a set number of connections, and re-uses those as you require them.

If the aim is to reduce the load on the SQL server, I would recommend something like a Web Service, which collects responses as they come in, and then batches them to the SQL server instead of posting each individual one directly in from the website itself.

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually think I understand now!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is it depends.

It will be faster if you insert/update multiple questions in one operation (either with linq or with a stored proc). You may however need to update it for every question so if the user is disconnected they wont lose their work.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to recreate the connection object inside the foreach loop, you can reuse the existing connection for all of the rows.

As for the impact of reconnecting practically there is none, since ADO.Net uses connection pooling, which means that when you disconnect from DB the ADO subsystem keeps the connection open for future reuse by another possible connection object.

As for LINQ, it is used for querying queryable objects, not for updating as in your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about 100 people (and not a web site with millions of users), I think you're fine. Don't do premature optimization, unless you see your SQL Server instance suffering.

As @Jroc says, SQL Server reuses the same pool of connections, so you don't have to worry about opening and closing the connection. SQL Server is designed to do so, and it's actually better to close your connection as soon as you're done with it than risking leaving connections open somewhere.

As for LINQ, it doesn't give you any performance advantage in this scenario (actually, for inserts and updates LINQ to SQL tends to do exactly what you're doing and issue one insert/update per row)

One last thing about your stored procedure: if you're on SQL 2008, you might want to take a look at the [MERGE command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), which combines your logic to "check if row exists, if yes update, if not insert" in one single command, and [may improve performance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879317.aspx) (and readability)